# Free Variables Interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a system of equations $At=b$ representing two planes in the euclidian space $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $A$ is $2\times 3$ and $t$ is $(x y z)$.

The matrix of the system has a 1-dimension NullSpace, that means the intersection of the planes shifted at the origin is a line.If the only possible free variables are x and y for example, does it mean the line is in the $x,y$ plane ?

If the only possible free variables are $x$ and $z$ for example, does it mean the line is in the $x,z$ plane?

As an extension of my doubt, if for example we had two hyperplanes ( $x,y,z,w$ as variables ) that intercepted in a plane and the only possible pair of free variables was $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ would that mean that the plan would not span the $w$ dimension , only the $x,y,z$ dimension ?

Comment: Nobody answers me this question :( i really need to remove this doubt from my head before moving on my learning process in Linear Algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Here is an outline of the possibilities:

**A Line in $\mathbb{R}^2$**

For a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, usually either $x$ or $y$ can serve as a free variable.  The exception is a horizontal line, for which only $x$ can be free, or vertical lines, for which only $y$ can be free.

**A Line in $\mathbb{R}^3$**

Something similar holds for a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  There are three cases:

1. Usually any of $x$, $y$, or $z$ can be a free variable.
2. However, if the direction of the line is perpendicular to one of the axes, then that variable can no longer be free.  For example, if a line is horizontal (perpendicular in direction to the $z$ axis, and parallel with the $xy$-plane), then $z$ is not an allowed free variable.
3. The last case is that the line is parallel to one of the axes—say the $x$-axis—in which case $x$ is the only possible free varaible.

**A Plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$**

For a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, there are again three cases:

1. Usually any two of the variables can be free.
2. However, if the plane is perpendicular to one of the coordinate planes, then that pair of variables can't be free.  For example, if a plane is vertical (perpendicular to the $xy$-plane), then $\{x,y\}$ is not an allowable set of free variables.
3. Finally, if a plane is parallel to one of the coordinate planes, then that is the only allowed set of free variables.  For example, if a plane is horizontal (parallel to the $xy$-plane), then $\{x,y\}$ is the *only* possible set of free variables.

**Things in $\mathbb{R}^4$**

Lines and hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ have *four* possibilities.  For a line, either any variable is allowed, or three are allowed, or two are allowed, or only one is allowed.  For a hyperplane, either any three are allowed, or one triple is excluded, or a certain pair is excluded (e.g. $x$ and $y$ can't simultaneously be free), or there is only one allowed triple.

Things get complicated for two-dimensional planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  There are *seven* different possibilities.  Here is an example of each:

1. Any two variables are allowed.  This is the most common situation.
2. Any two of $\{x,y,z\}$ are allowed, but $w$ is not allowed.  This happens when the direction of the plane is perpendicular to the $w$-axis.
3. Only $x$ and $y$ are allowed, and neither $z$ or $w$ can be free.  This happens when the plane is fully perpendicular (orthogonal) in direction to the $zw$-plane.
4. Any two except $\{x,y\}$ are allowed.  This happens when the plane contains a line whose direction is perpendicular to the $xy$-plane.
5. Either $x$ or $y$ or $z$ is allowed (but not two of these), and $w$ is required.  This happens when the plane is perpendicular to the $xyz$-subspace.
6. Either $x$ or $y$ is allowed (but not both), $z$ is required, and $w$ is not allowed.  This happens when the direction of the plane is perpendicular to the $w$-axis *and* the plane contains a line that's perpendicular in direction to the $xy$-plane.
7. Either $x$ or $y$ is allowed (but not both), and either $z$ or $w$ is allowed (but not both).  This happens when the plane contains a line perpendicular in direction to the $xy$-plane, and *also* contains a line perpendicular in direction to the $zw$-plane.

By the way, the possibilities listed here are known as [linear matroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matroid).  They correspond to the possible dependence relations between the columns of a matrix with a certain rank.  (In this case, the columns of a 4-column matrix with rank 2.)

Comment: By the way, when you said if the plane is paralel to one of the coordinate planes, you are saying that the plane IS one of the coordinate planes, right ? Because if it is paralel but not through the origin then it is not a subspace and can't correspond to the NullSpace.

Comment: My whole answer applies to any line or plane.  In the case of a line or plane through the origin (such as a nullspace), replace "parallel to" with "is equal to".

Comment: Right, thanks for the answer.